# how to define a range of past 14 candles?

Tags: pine-script

how to define a range of past 14 candles so that we can check whether a condition was true or false in that range?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(close) and
 plot(close)[1] and
  plot(close)[2] and
   plot(close)[3] and
    plot(close)[4] and
     plot(close)[5] and
      plot(close)[6] and
       plot(close)[7] and
        plot(close)[8] and
         plot(close)[9] and
          plot(close)[10] and
           plot(close)[11] and
            plot(close)[12] and
             plot(close)[13] and
              plot(close)[14]
```

This is the only thing I have been able to come up with.

I am also looking for a cleaner way to do this but have not figured it out yet. Something like `plot(close)[1-14]`, or even `plot(close)[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]` would be really nice, if possible.